# copying multiple folder to another destination with python

Tags: python, directory, copy

I would like to copy specific multiple folders to another destinanatin from a folder 300k folders in it I tried to do it but I coudn't How to I do that?

```py
import shutil
import os

base_path = ('\\\\10.52.16.9\Buildings')
dir_list = ['17145','17145','17169','17172','17174']
dest = os.path.join('C:/Users/user/Desktop/')

print("Before moving directories:")
print(os.listdir(base_path))

for dir_ in dir_list:
    source = os.path.join(base_path, dir_)
    if os.path.isdir(source):
        shutil.copytree(source, dest)

print("After moving directories:")
print(os.listdir(base_path))
```

Comment: "*I tried to do it but I coudn't*" Why, what happened? What error did you get?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: code simply doesn't work when I run the code It doesn't paste the folders ıt say:  fileexistserror winerror 183 cannot create a file when that file already exists